# Restify use() after route finishes

Tags: node.js, error-handling, restify

I tred to use "use()" method of Restify to do a generic error handling, e.g.,

```
server = restify.createServer({...});
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
...
app.post('/test/:id', function (req, res, next) {...})
server.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      logger.error({req: req}, "error processing request");

    });
```

but the last .use() handler was never called after route finished processing. 
It was "registered" after routes. I can see on server starts up, this .use() was processed after my routes were processed. I am fairly new to restify, so my question is, can the .user() method used to apply handler after route finishes. I know we can listen to 'after' event to do processing after route finishes, but would like to see if we can do .use() handler.

UPDATE:
Here is a simplified version of the code. The .use() methods registered before the server.post() were called but not the one registered after server.post(). Any suggestions?

```
var restify = require('restify');
var cookieParser = require('restify-cookies');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var util = require('util');
var logger = require('./util/logger');


module.exports = function(server){
  server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
  server.use(restify.queryParser());
  server.use(restify.bodyParser());

  server.use(helmet.noCache());
  server.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());

  server.use(cookieParser.parse);

  // this .use() method is called when accessing the server.post route below
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('BERORE ROUTE');
    return next();
  });

  server.post('/test/:returnId', function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new restify.errors.InternalServerError('oh noes!');
    return next(err);
  });

  // this .use() method is not called when accessing the server.post route above
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Tata...');
    return next();
  });
};
```

Comment: correction: a typo, app.post('/test/:id', function (req, res, next) {...}) should be server.post('/test/:id', function (req, res, next) {...})

Comment: @migg I did call next().  and the .use() methods before the server.post() were called, but not the one after server.post()

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to see the code inside

```
app.post('/test/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    // what is happening here?
});
```

I guess you do not call `next`, so the next middleware (your logging middleware in the use statement) is never called. So calling `next()` would call your middleware.

But maybe it would be better in your case to raise an error and handle the error as described in the [restify docs](http://restify.com/#error-handling):

```
app.post('/test/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    // some internal unrecoverable error
    var err = new restify.errors.InternalServerError('oh noes!');
    return next(err);
});

app.on('InternalServer', function (req, res, err, next) {
    //err.body = 'something is wrong!';
    logger.error({req: req}, "error processing request"); // <= from your code
    return next();
});
```

But this depends on what you want to achieve and what you are doing inside the `app.post`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your last "use" handler never gets called is because it doesn't exist in the handler chain at the time that handlers get assigned to the route. For each "use" call restify adds that handler to an array of handlers.

When a route function (get, post, etc.) gets called restify creates a chain of handlers that get called for that route. The chain of handlers for each route is built out of what you passed in for that route and it is PREPENDED with all the handlers that have been found by "use" calls so far.

So, when your server.post function call is processed the "Tata..." handler doesn't yet exist in the handler chain and therefore it is not prepended. That is why all "use" calls are always placed above the routes.

To illustrate this I placed two console.log statements inside the server.use function in restify. You can see the chain building with the middleware handlers (I named your functions "before" and "error_handler" so they could be indentified in the output). You can see that the last call to server.use results in a chain that includes all the middleware handlers, yet the handlers for the posttestreturnId route do not include "error_handler" because it wasn't in the array at the time it was called.

```
[ [Function: parseAccept] ] // the handler chain
{}                          // the routes and their handlers
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody],
  [Function: nocache] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody],
  [Function: nocache],
  [Function: hidePoweredBy] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody],
  [Function: nocache],
  [Function: hidePoweredBy],
  [Function: parseCookies] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody],
  [Function: nocache],
  [Function: hidePoweredBy],
  [Function: parseCookies],
  [Function: before] ]
{}
[ [Function: parseAccept],
  [Function: parseQueryString],
  [Function: readBody],
  [Function: parseBody],
  [Function: nocache],
  [Function: hidePoweredBy],
  [Function: parseCookies],
  [Function: before],
  [Function: error_handler] ]
{ posttestreturnid: 
  [ [Function: parseAccept],
    [Function: parseQueryString],
    [Function: readBody],
    [Function: parseBody],
    [Function: nocache],
    [Function: hidePoweredBy],
    [Function: parseCookies],
    [Function: before],
    [Function: returnId] ] }
```

Comment: Just hit this myself coming from Express to Restify, don't quite understand the logic behind this implementation as I can think of *loads* of reasons why you'd want middleware after the verb route.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function after other routes don't use server.use(), instead use below code.

```
 // this .use() method is called when accessing the server.post route below
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('BERORE ROUTE');
  return next();
});

server.post('/test/:returnId', function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new restify.errors.InternalServerError('oh noes!');
  return next(err);
});

server.on('after', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Tata...');
  return next();
});
```

As shown here http://restify.com/#audit-logging